# Merge SQL Queries for one result

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge

I have two SQL queries (SQL Server) which give me two results. I would like to merge the two queries to get one overall result. I have tried numerous permutations but none of them seem to work. Here are the two queries:

`SELECT DATEPART(YEAR,fld_one) [Year],
 DATEPART(QUARTER,fld_one) [Quarter],
 COUNT(1) [Licenses]
 FROM tbl_licenses
 GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR,fld_one),DATEPART(QUARTER,fld_one)
 ORDER BY 1,2`

`SELECT fld_company
FROM tbl_licenses
WHERE fld_quantity = (SELECT MAX(fld_quantity) FROM tbl_licenses)`

Basically I want the fld_quantity value to appear in a column beside `YEAR`, `QUARTER` and `LICENSES`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Show us sample table data, and the expected result!

Comment: Post sample data - also if you want "fld_quantity" to appear next to rows from your first query, you need to explain what columns relate the two datasets.  In other words, how do we know which rows from your first query correlate with the rows in your second?

Comment: "I have tried numerous permutations" which are?? No point people repeating those back to you just because you didn't rule them out.

Comment: put query one into a #temp table then join query 2 to it.

Comment: @DaveKelly A CTE would be cleaner (and _possibly_ more performant; I dunno).

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of it you need a primary and a foreign key, or at least two columns that you can do a SQL Join with, like date, ID, etc.

Try something like: Select * from tbl_licenses INNER JOIN tbl_licenses_v4 ON tbl_licenses_v4.ID = tbl_licenses.ID

[image]